# PCA using prcomp

Tags: r

I am using PCA prcomp to plot my data. what I need is to display the percentages of each Principles I mean PC1,..... on axes X and y the followings are my codes:

```
prcomp(x)
plot(prcomp(x))
summary(prcomp(x))
biplot(prcomp(x, scale=TRUE))
```

I do not know which codes I need to add in order to show PC percentages on each axis. Also when I type this code:

```
biplot(prcomp(mo, scale=TRUE))
```

it will automatically show PC1 and PC2 which code I should type to get the plots for PC2 and PC3 together for example.

Any hint would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The base R plotting methods for `prcomp` objects are rather basic. I would install the `ggfortify` package and look at [these examples](http://rpubs.com/sinhrks/plot_pca).

For example, the basic plot shows the percentage variance explained by each PC on the axes labels. This is an alternative to the "screeplot" bars:

```
library(ggfortify)
pc1 <- prcomp(iris[, 1:4]
autoplot(pc1, data = iris, colour = "Species")
```

[image]

You specify different PCs using the `x` and `y` arguments. You can also show the loadings, as in a biplot.

```
autoplot(pc1, data = iris, 
              colour = "Species", 
              loadings = TRUE, 
              loadings.label = TRUE, x = 2, y = 3)
```

[image]

If you did want a screeplot with bars, you can access `sdev` in the `prcomp` object:

```
library(tidyverse)
data.frame(sd = pc1$sdev) %>% 
  mutate(pct = 100 * (sd/sum(sd))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(1:4, pct)) + geom_col()
```

[image]